# Java HTMLUnit getByFirstXPath not working

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I am trying to load a page and click a link using HTMLUnit 2.4 in Java.  I am attempting to find the calendar on a page by xPath.  It is returning null.  The xPath was copied directly out of Chrome DevTools.  I used Chrome DevTools Network tab to see that the very first resource loaded to the page contains the data I want.  I don't think this is AJAX related.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        HtmlPage homePage = webClient.getPage("http://bay.realtaxdeed.com");
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        HtmlDivision calendarButtonDiv = homePage.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"splashMenuBottom\"]");
        HtmlPage currentMonthPage = calendarButtonDiv.click();

        HtmlElement element = currentMonthPage.getElementById("MAIN_TBL_CONTENT");
        HtmlDivision calendarDivision = currentMonthPage.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"MAIN_TBL_CONTENT\"]/div[2]/div/div[11]");

        System.out.println( "Run complete." );
    }
}
```

I had to disable the javascript to avoid getting an error on the landing page.  I re-enable to try and ensure the WebClient performs like a normal browser.  I successfully get the calendarButtonDiv by xpath.  I click that to get the page with the calendar.  My goal is to click the days with hyperlinks in them.

Why can't I find the calendar (calendarDivision) by xPath?  What is the proper way to find elements using HTMLUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HtmlUnit version you are using is now 9 years old. Please try this with the latest version. Usually this kind of problems are related to different dom trees and there where many changes/fixes done by the reals browsers and also in HtmlUnit.

Next step is to dump the page from HtmlUnit (page.asXML()) and have a look if your XPath does fit.

And finally if you think the dom tree generated by HtmlUnit (latest version) differs from the one of real browsers; please open an issue and provide a simple html that shows the problem. Usually we can then fix this kind of problems fast.

Comment: Thanks RBRi.  That versioning is really weird.  I wouldn't think that 2.31 is 9 years newer than 2.4.  I have a host of other problems now that I need to work through.  Over the last 9 years this library has changed quite a bit.  Thanks again.