# Constructing corrext xpath for HtmlUnit

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to scrape a webpage with HtmlUnit but I cannot get past the login screen. I think I am building the XPath wrong but I am using the one given by the browser.

WebPage: `https://www.swaper.com/#/dashboard`

My code for autologin

```
private static WebClient autoLogin(String login, String password) throws IOException {
    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    HtmlPage loginPage = client.getPage(SWAPER_LOGIN_PAGE);

    HtmlInput inputLogin = loginPage.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"form\"]/div/div[1]/div/input");
    HtmlInput inputPassword = loginPage.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"form\"]/div/div[2]/div/input");
    inputLogin.setValueAttribute(login);
    inputPassword.setValueAttribute(password);

    HtmlForm loginForm = inputPassword.getEnclosingForm();
    client.getPage(loginForm.getWebRequest(null));

    return client;

}
```

I get the loginPage without any problems but I always get null on the HtmlInput objects. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: HtmlUmit sometimes show weird behaviour not understanding Xpathes that are correct. Have checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412200/java-htmlunit-getbyfirstxpath-not-working.

Comment: Use page.asXml() to check the dom tree.

Comment: I used the asXml() and found out their website does not work well with disabled javascript so I have to enable it and resolve errors when JS is enabled. Thank you.